# How can I migrate from phpBB 3.x to SMF?

Tags: forum, phpbb, migration

I have a phpBB 3.x-based site which I would like to migrate to SMF - basically, all threads, posts, user accounts and possibly PMs.

This seems to be possible, but I haven't been able to find a solid tutorial/ guide that can help me through this.

Does anybody have any experience doing this or know of a good guide that can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?P=ebedf968a32ad2c389eac10b83c56115&topic=218449.0) should help you, it is one of many converters you can find by doing a quick google.

I think this was the one I used when I moved a small phpBB install to SMF.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks - I'll see how I get on with it.